# Cannot add foreign key on already existing table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, foreign-keys, database-migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('partial_trips', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->unsignedInteger('driver_user_id')->after('main_trip_id');
        });

        Schema::table('partial_trips', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('driver_user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

*I had created exactly the same FK, with the same relation, in another table*, when the table was being initialized. But this one does not work. I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or u  
  pdate a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bpr`.`#sql-7c82_5  
  7d`, CONSTRAINT `partial_trips_driver_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`  
  driver_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Looking at other posts, concerning that problem, I could find only cases where the column was not `unsigned` or one of the columns in the relation was not existent. Here, I have covered both of these cases and don't know what the problem might be...

Comment: got any data in the tables? Can't add an FK if there's orphan records in the table(s).

Comment: Yeah, both the referencing and the referenced tables have data.

Comment: you'll have to fix the orphan records first, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some data in the table means the constraint will fail because the added columns will be set to NULL for the existing rows.
Inside migrations every column definition is not nullable by default. You will have to specify nullable to allow null values for the foreign key.

```
$table->integer('driver_user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('main_trip_id');
```